# Using MYSQL database on PC without MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans

I created a test database for my Java program which connects to it. Now I want to use it on another PC without this test database. Is it possible to create an instance of my database to install it on a certain PC?

Notes:

- The PC I want to use my Database on has no MYSQL installed

Questions:

- How can I setup my database with a batch file?
- Do I need to install MYSQL first or is it possible to use my database without it?
- If MYSQL needs to be installed, how can I do it and how can I include my already created tables via batch file?

Edit:

We already have the tables but a new database should be installed on when the program starts the first time.

Comment: What about using an embedded database, like java Derby, or the faster H2 database? Smaller footprint. JDBC is vendor independent.

Comment: i have no clue how to do such a thing...

Comment: Use **mysqlimport**. See my answer.

Comment: i got the task wrong, i just have to open the installer with a .batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can import your data on PC without installation of MySQL using **[mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html)**.

```
shell> mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]
```

There are many options available for [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html). See here [mysqlimport --help, -?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_help).

**NOTE :** It uses **.txt** file.